# Need some AR Toolkit for .Net?

Tags: augmented-reality

I need some list of Augmented Reality toolkit that can work with .Net. I want to implement it with basic .Net for windows not with WPF or Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpfull to you [SLARToolkit - Silverlight and Windows Phone Augmented Reality Toolkit](http://slartoolkit.codeplex.com/)

> **Features**:-
>
> - Direct Support for Silverlight's CaptureSource
> - Support for Windows Phone's Photo Camera class
> - Built-in support for Silverlight 5's hardware accelerated 3D API
> - Flexible through a generic and a WriteableBitmap detector
> - Multiple marker detection
> - Simple black square markers
> - Custom markers
> - Real time performance
> - Easy to use
> - Documentation including a step by step Beginner's Guide
> - Based on established algorithms and techniques
> - Uses the Matrix3DEx library

Comment: I have already checked the SLAR Toolkit. It's good but is there any other toolkit available.

Comment: I have heard of one more mxr toolkit but I have no idea about it. Does slar not solves your purpose???